# Chatter Moderator User Security Token

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

This is the my problem in very short way;

Is it possible to get security token for Chatter Moderator User on salesforce ?

Answer (score 0):

A Chatter Moderator is just a normal user with some special permissions, so yes, that user can log in and retrieve his security token by going to Setup (or by clicking on his own name in the new Setup UI) and going to Personal Information -> Reset My Security Token.